# How to mock a function that returns a user object

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-unittest, django-testing

I am trying to mock a method that returns a user object like so

```
@mock.patch('impersonate.helpers.which_user', return_value=self.user2)
    def test_user_can_retrieve_favs_using_impersonation(self):
```

It's failing with the error: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`
. I defined `self.user2` in the setup method of the test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `self` in the decorator - the object is not defined yet at the point this is parsed.

Instead you can move the patching into the method:

```py
def test_user_can_retrieve_favs_using_impersonation(self):
    with mock.patch('impersonate.helpers.which_user', return_value=self.user2):
        ...
```

or

```py
def test_user_can_retrieve_favs_using_impersonation(self):
    with mock.patch('impersonate.helpers.which_user') as mocked: 
        mocked.return_value=self.user2
        ...
```